# Override SQL constraint

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

res.currency.rate has this original constraint

```
CONSTRAINT res_currency_rate_currency_uniq UNIQUE (name)
```

can I override it somehow to make it a unique name for each currency and not unique name per all table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
 _sql_constraints = [('res_currency_uni1ue', 'CHECK(1=1)', 'This is unique!')]
```